# Hashed password not coming out to what it should be (PHP)

Tags: php, mysqli, hash

So I'm trying to make a fairly simple login system, but for some reason the hashed password that is being sent to my database is not hashing correctly. I checked my database and the stored password is not what the sha256 hashed with the generated salt appended is not what it's supposed to be. Here's my code for generating the hash that's being uploaded to the database:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
//Check Connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    echo "Failed to connect to server: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Reset all Checks
$username_exists = NULL;
$email_valid = NULL;
$passwords_match = NULL;
$password_acceptable = NULL;
$password_long_enough = NULL;
$password = NULL;

//Prepare Statements
    //Check for Username Existing Statement
    $check_username_match = $connect->stmt_init();
    $sql_check_username = "SELECT id FROM $tablename WHERE username=?";
    $check_username_match->prepare($sql_check_username);
    $check_username_match->bind_param("s", $username);

    //Insert Into Table Statement
    $register_query = $connect->stmt_init();
    $sql_register = "INSERT INTO $tablename (username, email, password, token, active, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $register_query->prepare($sql_register);
    $register_query->bind_param("sssssi", $username, $email, $hashedpassword, $token, $activated, $level);

//Execute When Form Submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

    //Check if Username Exists
    $check_username_match->execute();
    $check_username_match->store_result();
    $numrows = $check_username_match->num_rows;
    if ($numrows==0){
        $username_exists = false;
    } else {
        $username_exists=true;
    }

    //Check if Passwords Match
    if ($password==$confirm_password){
        $passwords_match = true;
    } else {
        $passwords_match = false;
    }

    //Check if Email Address is Valid
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_valid = true;
    } else {
        $email_valid = false;
    }

    //Check if Passwords Contains Special Characters
    $uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);
    $lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password);
    $number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password);
    //Check if Password is Long Enough
    $password_length = strlen($password);
    if ($password_length>8){
        $password_long_enough = true;
    } else {
        $password_long_enough = false;
    }

    //Validate Password
    if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$password_long_enough || $password = '') {
        $password_acceptable = false;
    } else {
        $password_acceptable = true;
    }

    //Register if all Validations Met
    if(!$username_exists && $email_valid && $passwords_match && $password_acceptable){
        //$salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));
        $token = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));
        $activated="No"; 
        $level = 0;
        $hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $register_query->execute();
        $message = "Hello, welcome to the site.\r\n\r\nPlease click on the following link to activate your account:\r\nlocalhost/login_system/activate.php?token=".$token;
        mail($email, 'Please Activate Your Account', $message);
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
?>
```

UPDATE: I changed my above code to reflect the changes I made with password_hash. However, the problem still persists.

This is my login php:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();
//Reset Variables
$message = '';
$location = "/login_system/index.php"; //default location to redirect after logging in
$username = '';
$password = '';

//Check to see if user is newly activated; if he is display a welcome message.
    if(isset($_GET['activated'])){
        if($_GET['activated'] == "true"){
            $message = "Thank you for verifying your account. Please login to continue.";
        }
    }

//Check to see if user is coming from another page; if he is then store that page location to redirect to after logging in.
if(isset($_GET['location'])) {
    $location =  htmlspecialchars($_GET['location']);
}

echo $location;

//Prepare login check statement
    $check_login = $connect->stmt_init();
    $sql = "SELECT id, password FROM $tablename WHERE username=?";
    $check_login->prepare($sql);
    $check_login->bind_param("s", $username);

//Execute Login Check
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $username = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $check_login->execute();
        $check_login->store_result();
        $numrows = $check_login->num_rows;
        $check_login->bind_result($id, $match);
        $check_login->fetch();
        if ($numrows==1 && password_verify($password, $match)) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $id;
            $goto = "localhost".$location;
            header("location: $goto");
            $message = "Success!";  
        } else {
            $message="Username or password is not valid."."<br>".$match."<br>";
        }
    }
    $connect->close();
?>
```

Comment: don't roll your own use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Is sha256 not good enough? I'm not really making my own hashing function here. I'm just not sure why it's not storing the right hashed value!

Comment: @Dagon I updated my code to use those functions but it's still not submitting the correct hash appearntly, because I cannot login. I think my password is getting changed somewhere before being hashed on the registration page... I just can't find where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just feed the password you want to hash into PHP's `password_hash();`function. Like so...

```
$password = $_POST['password'];

$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Then when you want to check if the password exists in the database use `password_verify();` Like so...

```
$password = PASSWORD_HERE;
$stored_hash = HASH_HERE;

if (password_verify($password, $stored_hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: I just read up on this and implemented just what you told me to. However, it's still not authenticating. I think my registration code is messed up somewhere, but I can't find where.

Comment: There is no error in the code. I think that my inputted password is getting messed around with on the registration page, because when I use the same hashing function on the login page (for the same password) it's not the same as whatever the hashed function is uploaded into the database.

Comment: Is the login page just HTML form elements? If so I don't see how that could be the problem.

Comment: Yep. Actually, adding a "$password = $_POST['password'];" RIGHT before I hash the password seemed to fix the problem. So my $password variable was being changed since it was defined on line 33... any ideas why?

Comment: The variable should have a value before you hash it.